# MySQL Authentication against OpenLDAP Failure

Tags: authentication, centos7, openldap, sasl, mysql5

I'm trying to set up OpenLDAP authentication on a MySQL Commercial Server (5.7.21)

I've followed all the steps described on MySQL web https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/ldap-pluggable-authentication.html#ldap-pluggable-authentication-installation

But when I try to log with an LDAP account I have the following error in `mysql-error.log`

```
[ERROR] Plugin authentication_ldap_sasl reported: 'Plug-in has failed to read the packet from client'

[ERROR] Plugin authentication_ldap_sasl reported: 'LDAP authentication failed or group retrieval failed:  LDAP error: Operations error'
```

What I'm missing ????

OpenLDAP and MySQL servers are located in differents VMs, but the same LAN, both VMS can communicate between them, but I have no packet arriving to LDAP (verified with `tcpdump`)

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing recently the same problem , after searching I came to that:

Knowing that the plugin uses cyrus library for sasl mechanism, and the only supported is scram-sha-1, you have to check if  **cyrus-sasl-scram** plugin is installed

- first

  I succeded to connect to the server by installing this package :

  ```
  $sudo yum install  cyrus-sasl-scram
  ```
- Second

  check also if the scarm-sha-1 is activated in the ldap server by using this command in the ldap client :

  ```
  $ldapsearch -LLL -x -b "" -s base objectclass=* supportedSASLMechanisms
  ```

Good luck